# How can I check if the component is unmounted in a functional component?

Tags: reactjs

A callback function sets the component state. But sometimes subscription which supplies the data need to end. Because callback is executed asynchronously, it's not aware if the subscription ends just after making the service call (which executes the callback function).

Then I see following error in the console:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
>   This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
>   To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
>   cleanup function.

Is there a way to access the component state, even if I am in the callback function?

This would be the steps:

- subscribe with parameters
- unsubscribe
- component is unmounted
- subscribed service executes the callback function
- callback functio sets state in an unmounted component and it gives error above

Comment: I guess you use [hooks useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) You can use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) (suggested in the error) to return a [cleanup function](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/data-list/blob/master/Animate/index.js#L56) to mutate a [mounted variable](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/data-list/blob/master/Animate/index.js#L45) and check [that variable before calling the useState function](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/data-list/blob/master/Animate/index.js#L12)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is some pseudo code how you can use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to see if a component is mounted.

It uses useEffect to listen to `someService` when it receives a message it checks if the component is mounted (cleanup function is also called when component unmounts) and if it is it uses `setServiceMessage` that was created by [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to set messages received by the service:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import someService from 'some-service';

export default props => {
  const userId = props.userId;
  const [serviceMessage, setServiceMessage] = useState([]);
  useEffect(
    () => {
      const mounted = { current: true };
      someService.listen(
        //listen to messages for this user
        userId, 
        //callback when message is received
        message => {
          //only set message when component is mounted
          if (mounted.current) {
            setServiceMessage(serviceMessage.concat(message));
          }
      });
      //returning cleanup function
      return () => {
        //do not listen to the service anymore
        someService.stopListen(userId);
        //set mounted to false if userId changed then mounted
        //  will immediately be set to true again and someService
        //  will listen to another user's messages but if the 
        //  component is unmounted then mounted.current will 
        //  continue to be false
        mounted.current = false;
      };
    },//<-- the function passed to useEffects
    //the function passed to useEffect will be called
    //every time props.userId changes, you can pass multiple
    //values here like [userId,otherValue] and then the function
    //will be called whenever one of the values changes
    //note that when this is an object then {hi:1} is not {hi:1}
    //referential equality is checked so create this with memoization
    //if this is an object created by mapStateToProps or a function
    [userId]
  );
};
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use a ref like this:

```
const mounted = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
    mounted.current = true;

    return () => { mounted.current = false; };
}, []);
```

Then in your callback you can check if `mounted.current === false` and avoid setting the state

Comment: Very clean and easy solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can return a function from **useEffect**, which will be fired when a functional component unmount.
[Please read this](https://dev.to/robmarshall/how-to-use-componentwillunmount-with-functional-components-in-react-2a5g)

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
const ComponentExample = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        // Anything in here is fired on component mount.
        return () => {
            // Anything in here is fired on component unmount.
        }
    }, [])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This hook (insired from Mohamed answer) solves the problem in a more elegant maner:

```
function useMounted() {
  const mounted = useMemo(() => ({ current: true }), []);
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => { mounted.current = false}
  }, [mounted]);
  return mounted;
}
```

(Updated to use useMemo instead of useRef for readability).

Comment: This solution looks clean, but I don't understand the user of useRef in this context.

Comment: I've updated the code sample. It's not using useRef anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I found the accepted answer to this question hard to read, and React provides their own [documentation on just this question](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1). Their example is:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function FriendStatus(props) {
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleStatusChange(status) {
      setIsOnline(status.isOnline);
    }
    ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
    // Specify how to clean up after this effect:
    return function cleanup() {
      ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
    };
  });

  if (isOnline === null) {
    return 'Loading...';
  }
  return isOnline ? 'Online' : 'Offline';
}
```

I've created a component I call `<Fade>` that will fade in/out any children its given. Note that it relies on bootstrap's `.fade` and `.show` classes, though these could easily be implemented without bootstrap.

```js
const Fade: React.FC<{}> = ({ children }) => {
  const [ className, setClassName ] = useState('fade')
  const [ newChildren, setNewChildren ] = useState(children)

  useEffect(() => {
    setClassName('fade')

    const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
      setClassName('fade show')
      setNewChildren(children)
    }, TIMEOUT_DURATION)

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timerId)
    }   

  }, [children])

  return <Container fluid className={className + ' p-0'}>{newChildren}</Container>
}
```

It all boils down to one rule: *unsubscribe from your asynchronous tasks in the cleanup function returned from `useEffect`*.